# Regular expression non-greedy but still

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have some larger text which in essence looks like this:

```
abc12..manycharshere...hi - abc23...manyothercharshere...jk
```

Obviously there are two items, each starting with "abc", the numbers (12 and 23) are interesting as well as the "hi" and "jk" at the end.

I would like to create a regular expression which allows me to parse out the numbers, but only if the two characters at the end match, i.e. I am looking for the number related to "jk", but the following regular expression matches the whole string and thus returns "12", not "23" even when non-greedy matching the area with the following:

```
abc([0-9]+).*?jk
```

Is there a way to construct a regular expression which matches text like the one above, i.e. retrieving "23" for items ending in "jk"?

Basically I would need something like "match abc followed by a number, but only if there is "jk" at the end before another instance of "abc followed by a number appears"

Note: the texts/matches are an abstraction here, the actual text is more complicated, espially the things that can appear as "manyothercharactershere", I simplified to show the underlying problem more clearly.

Comment: Can you split the string reliably to separate the "abc..." segments? Say on the "-" character? What can appear inside "manyothercharactershere"? Can it have "abc" in it?

Comment: The negative lookahead was what I was looking for, it works nicely now, thanks!

Comment: Negative look-ahead won't work when "manyothercharactershere" might have an "abc" in it.

Comment: Yes, but I can rule that out, actually I ended up using a regular expression which uses ".*" in front so it matches everything up to the last occurrence of "abc" before "jk". It seems to be a CPU heavy regex with larger text, but still finishes in acceptable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex like this. `.*abc([0-9]+).*?jk`

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mK1jK8/2)

Comment: Actually this one seems to do it in the best way, using negative lookahead above did not work for all my cases...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this,

```
abc([0-9]+)(?=(?:(?!jk|abc[0-9]).)*jk)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eT2uY9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use negative lookahead here to make it work:

```
abc(?!.*?abc)([0-9]+).*?jk
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bS6sH2/1)

Here `(?!.*?abc)` is negative lookahead that makes sure to match `abc` where it is NOT followed by another `abc` thus making sure closes string between `abc` and `jk` is matched.

Answer (score 1):

Being non-greedy does not change the rule, that the first match is returned. So `abc([0-9]+).*?jk` will find the first `jk` after “`abc`*number*” rather than the last one, but still match the first “`abc`*number*”.

One way to solve this is to tell that the dot should not match `abc([0-9]+)`:

```
abc([0-9]+)((?!abc([0-9]+)).)*jk
```

---

If it is not important to have the entire pattern being an exact match you can do it simpler:

```
.*(abc([0-9]+).*?jk)
```

In this case, it’s group 1 which contains your intended match. The pattern uses a greedy matchall to ensure that the last possible “`abc`*number*” is matched within the group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that hyphen separates "items", this regex will capture the numbers from the target item:

```
abc([0-9]+)[^-]*?jk
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/SZsrrZd7RX)